# Discord.js don't execute client.on("message")

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to build a Discord's bot using **discord.js** with **NodeJS** but i'm facing a problem. When I run the code, the dicord.js don't execute the **client.on("message")**, he just skips this part and go to the end of the code, like you can see in the following image:

[image]

**index.js**

```
    const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require("./config.json");
require('dotenv').config();

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

const queue = new Map();

client.once("ready", c => {
  console.log(` [${c.user.tag}] Running...`);
  client.user.setActivity(`${prefix}play`, { type: "PLAYING" })
});

client.once("reconnecting", c => {
  console.log(` [${c.user.tag}] Reconnecting...`);
});

client.once("disconnect", c => {
  console.log(`[${c.user.tag}] Disconnect!`);
});


client.on("message", async message => {
  console.log("I'm here!")
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
    execute(message, serverQueue);
    return;
  } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}skip`)) {
    skip(message, serverQueue);
    return;
  } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}stop`)) {
    stop(message, serverQueue);
    return;
  } else {
    message.channel.send("You need to enter a valid command!");
  }
});

async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
  const args = message.content.split(" ");

  const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
  if (!voiceChannel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You need to be in a voice channel to play music!"
    );
  const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
  if (!permissions.has("CONNECT") || !permissions.has("SPEAK")) {
    return message.channel.send(
      "I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!"
    );
  }

  const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
  const song = {
        title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
        url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url,
   };

  if (!serverQueue) {
    const queueContruct = {
      textChannel: message.channel,
      voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
      connection: null,
      songs: [],
      volume: 5,
      playing: true
    };

    queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

    queueContruct.songs.push(song);

    try {
      var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
      queueContruct.connection = connection;
      play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      queue.delete(message.guild.id);
      return message.channel.send(err);
    }
  } else {
    serverQueue.songs.push(song);
    return message.channel.send(`${song.title} has been added to the queue!`);
  }
}

function skip(message, serverQueue) {
  if (!message.member.voice.channel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
    );
  if (!serverQueue)
    return message.channel.send("There is no song that I could skip!");
  serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function stop(message, serverQueue) {
  if (!message.member.voice.channel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
    );
    
  if (!serverQueue)
    return message.channel.send("There is no song that I could stop!");
    
  serverQueue.songs = [];
  serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function play(guild, song) {
  const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
  if (!song) {
    serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
    queue.delete(guild.id);
    return;
  }

  const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
    .play(ytdl(song.url))
    .on("finish", () => {
      serverQueue.songs.shift();
      play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    })
    .on("error", error => console.error(error));
  dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
  serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Start playing: **${song.title}**`);
}

client.login(token);
```

May you help to solve this problem?

Comment: client.on is an event listener. It will only be executed when you get an "message" event.
Do you receive a message and it still wont get executed?

Comment: Worth noting that [the `message` event is deprecated](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) in the latest release of Discord.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is true that the `message` event is deprecated, you should still be getting process warnings when using it.

The main issue is that you haven't added intents for guild messages, your bot can't see messages. Add `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES` to your client intents.

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

For what I saw on their [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) and based on the comment from @esqew, they deprecated the message event.
You should try `client.on("messageCreate")`